# Ubuntu 18.04 Steam Installation - Missing Packages

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-center, dependencies, steam

I am trying to install Steam in several ways (which is just the same way under different paths of actions but it all feels completely different)

Now many different sources like e.g. the three links below which are detailing how to get Steam in Ubuntu are met with the same issue: *unmet dependencies from missing packages*:

- [linuxconfig.org: How to install Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
- [linuxize.com: How To Install Steam on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
- [OMG Ubuntu: How To Install Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 (and Above)](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install steam
[...skipped 30 lines of text]
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When performing the install from the Software Center itself, I simply fail to get a list of the missing packages, it only shows:

> Unable to install "Steam Installer":
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:

[Only other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714447/missing-steam-packages) on askubuntu getting close to my issues (yet not being quite the same thing)

I am unable to understand as of now how to simply go find packages it seems, though I have been through this in every installation process so far.

Anyone understand what my PC is asking me in this above-mentioned text?

UPDATE: Running the commands posted by [@Grammargeek](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636500/why-cant-i-download-steam/1142241?noredirect=1#comment1894320_1142241) taken [from a team from Valve](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/blob/master/README.md) produced this

```
$ wget -o ~/steam.deb https://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
```

Which I suppose got the right content (please correct me if need be)

Then ran

```
$ sudo gdebi ~/steam.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Failed to open the software package
The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file. Check the permissions of the file.
```

I will attempt starting anew

Comment: "Unmet" in this case does NOT mean *missing* dependencies, it means *wrong version* dependencies. You won't be able to add, remove, or upgrade software until you resolve the *version conflicts* you have introduced.

Comment: How I understand this statement (sorry this is almost chinese to me Im not a software engineer :S) is that some packages present on the system are 'broken' (?) 

I am currently trying to run Synaptic PM to see if it will find anything. 

Also tried to kill processes running apt which might have kept the lock status (would not be surprised if I manually broke a process that was trying to install things in apt by playing around with to many things things)

Comment: 'Broken' doesn't mean broken-like-a-window. It means you have unwisely installed something that has *broken apt's logic* (most usually a wrong-version package). Killing apt processes is unwise - doing it wrong will keep the apt lock instead of releasing it...and that's not the problem you showed us anyway. You have a simple choice: You can go down the rabbit-hole and learn about apt dependencies in-depth (Learning Path), or your can revert all your changes or simply backup-and-reinstall (Make-It-Work Path). Your choice.